# Error when trying to modify/create a view on the default image libary in SP 2013

Tags: document-library, view, picture-library, sharepoint-library, default

I get an error when trying to modify a view or create a new view on the default image library in SP 2013. I have no issue creating or modifying views on a default document libaray or other custom list or libraries,only the default image library... any reason why this may be happening?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: "Sorry Something went wrong" an unexpected error has been occurred

Comment: Do you have access to the logs?

Comment: unfortunately, I do not

Comment: ok. Can you create another site and check if you get the same issue?

Comment: i will try that on Monday when I am back in the office...if the error still happens what would be your next step...? thanks for your help!

Comment: If there is no content then you can create a new one and delete this one. Was this library migrated from a previous version?

Comment: i created a subsite and the image library was the default library when you create a site you get that as default, so there was no content in the library because it was OOTB sp image library

Comment: Ok. Then try crearing new image library and check if you can create views.